# Domain is not working

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have purchased a domain name from Godaddy. I would like to point this domain to a server EC2 instance on AWS. On my registrar's web site I specified AWS name servers which i created using Amazon Route 53. Using Route 53 I created specified DNS record (NS, A, SOA) please have a look at screenshot. I waited > 24 hours for changes to propagate but I can't access my website via my domain name.

[image]

I  have created one A record mydomain.in but still my site didn't work then i created two more A records named as www.mydomain.in and *.mydomain.in but didn't work this time as well.

Please let me know what's incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is your domain actually `mydomain.in`?

Comment: In either case, I'd recommend using the tool `dig` to find out if your `NS` records are actually correct first, for example `dig mydomain.in ns`. If the NS records match yours, try `dig mydomain.in a` to ensure that it's value is right. If those are all correct, check the security groups on your instance.

Comment: @Jamie: Thanks for your time...No, it's not actual domain....I have already run dig command and it's showing the same nameservers which are being displayed on Amazon Route 53

Answer (score 0):

Your Domain Name is still pointing to other nameservers [ns1.bodis.com, ns2.bodis.com] than the ones on your route53. you need to change that !

To do so you can refer to this [tutorial](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-godaddy-12317)
and then you can fill in the NS fields with the ones given in Route53 [ns-1825.awsdns-32.co.uk, ...]

Comment: Thanks for your time...the domain which you checked is dummy domain (took only for example).....i have checked nameservers details using dig command....I had already set custom nameservers on Godaddy (as per suggested link)...is there something else which i am missing?